# how to determine datagridview current state (insert - edit - display) mode vs2008 windows app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

how to determine datagridview current state (insert - edit - display) mode vs2008
windows applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trans_dBindingSource.EndEdit();

if (stock_dataset.trans_d.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added) != null)
{
    saveToolStripButton.PerformClick();
}
if (stock_dataset.trans_d.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified) != null)
{
    saveToolStripButton.PerformClick();
}
if (stock_dataset.trans_d.GetChanges(DataRowState.Unchanged) != null)
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bindingsource.endedit();
if(dataset.datatable.getchanges(datarowstate.added) != null)
{
add mode
}

bindingsource.endedit();
if(dataset.datatable.getchanges(datarowstate.modefied) != null)
{
modify mode
}

bindingsource.endedit();
if(dataset.datatable.getchanges(datarowstate.unchanged) != null)
{
no changes mode
}
```